# Passing more then one value with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to pass more then one value in `GET` request with JS.

However, the way I am currently trying it does not work.

The function I am using for that is given below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updatestatus(status, id){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","adminfunction.php?status="+status"id="+id,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
  }
</script>
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&` to your url when you pass another variable.

You also forgot a `+`.

Change :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","adminfunction.php?status="+status"id="+id,false);
```

To :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","adminfunction.php?status="+status+"&id="+id,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add and `&` in your url

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","adminfunction.php?status="+status"id="+id + "&another=" + newVar,false);
```